# R grepl variable comparison

Tags: r, regex, string, string-comparison

Just need some help with `grepl`, it's doing my head in!

I have two variables:

```
str1<-"AAV.L"
str2<-"AAV2.L"
```

And what I want to do is check if `str2` is an extension of `str1` (which it is in this case). Basically here `str2` has an extra `"2"` in it's name..

Ideally the solution is something like:

```
grepl(str1,paste0(str2,...))
```

But I have no idea to account for the `.` in `str1`. The lengths of variables aren't the same either so I can't just check if the first 3 characters of `str1` are present in `str2`.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT - Clarification..

Basically by "extension of" I mean if one variable contains exactly the same letters, and more, in the same order. So the above example, `AAV.L` and `AAV2.L` would match because it contains `AAV..L`. It doesn't have to be like this however, it should match `REWR` with `REWRLE` as well meaning `REWR..`.

So `c("AAV.LE", "BAAV.L","AABV.L","AAV..L","ABCAV.L")`, none would match. If I were to put a rule for the match into plain English it would be:
*Does `str2` start with `str1` OR does `str2` start with any subset of `str1` and end with the other subset?*

I've taken a look into `agrep` but it matches too inaccurately. For example `AAV.L` and `AAV2.L` match which is good, but then `ADD` and `APUAD` do as well, which is incorrect! I know I can specify `max.distance` but some strings could be `ADD` and `ADDDDDDDDD` which would make settings this value implausible..

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Can you specify the problem better? How exactly do you define whether one string is "an extension of" another?

Comment: Also, do you have to use `grepl`? Depending on your answer to my last comment I think it might be easier to not use regexes.

Comment: -1 and vote to close: you do not provide sufficient examples or explanation to uniquely determine what you want. What in `c("AAV.LE", "BAAV.L","AABV.L","AAV..L","ABCAV.L")` should match? You might want to look at `agrep`.

Comment: If you edit your question to be more precise, I will nominate to reopen the question.

Comment: Sorry guys, was in a rush and on holidays! I have edited the question for more clarification.

Comment: I think the last update made it *more* confusing. The different ways of saying it seem to contradict each other. "Exactly the same letters, and more, in the same order" implies that `Some people see things that are and ask why. Some people dream of things that never were and ask why not. Some people have to go to work and don't have time for all that.` is an "extension" of `hello`.  But your "plain English" version says something completely different. It says that str2 has to *start with* characters from str1, and that either it has to start with all of them together...

Comment: ...or start with any subset of them, and end with "the other subset" (I take it that means the remaining characters from str1 that aren't at the beginning?), which implies that they don't all have to be in the same order (unless you mean "parts" and not "subsets", and the two subsets have to be clumped together at the beginning and end, with any additional characters that aren't in str1 in between the two subsets.  Take a look at what you wronte, I think that you'll find that it doesn't say whatever it is that you intended it to say (which I really have no idea about).

Comment: Also, according to your english definition, aren't "AABV.L" and "ABCAV.L" an extension of "AAV..L"? in the first case you have "AA" + "B" + "V.L" (you said that it's only letters that matter, not the dots). In the second your have "A" + "BC" + "AV.L" (these are both cases of starts with a subset and ends with the rest)? Additionally, "AAV.LE" starts with "AAV..L" (again you mentioned that it's only letters that count, not periods) so "AAV.LE" is an extension of "AAV..L"???

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys. Though I don't know where you're getting these responses from, I have figured it out using @BlueMagister's response. Here it is: `agrep(str1,str2,costs=list(ins=0,del=10,sub=10))` basically allow insertions to cost nothing. Unfortunately this still means `AAP` will match with `A1A2P2` but for the strings I am working with, it should be fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could drop the dot extension before placing in grepl.

```
str1 <- sub("\\.[[:alnum:]]+$", "", str1);
## AAV

str2 <- sub("\\.[[:alnum:]]+$", "", str2);
## AAV2
```

Note: This is a method for removing file extensions. It won't remove any other occurances of the dot character. It works by replacing an occurance of a period followed by nothing but alphanumeric characters, and searches from the end of the string. It replaces it with an empty ("") string.

```
str3 <- "A.A.V.L"
str3 <- sub("\\.[[:alnum:]]+$", "", str3);
## A.A.V
```

Then, using grepl

```
grepl(str1, str2)
## TRUE
```

Comment: Hi @DashAnimal, thanks for the answer. Don't know if this is really practical for large numbers of comparisons and for larger strings. Edited question, maybe it would help breed a new answer?